# the functions (procedures) in MIPS

Tags: function, mips, procedure

I'm new in MIPS language and I don't understand how the functions (procedures) in the MIPS assembly language work. Here are but I will specify my problem :

1. What does:

   - `jal`
   - `jr`
   - `$ra`

   mean in mips language and the important thing
2. How can we use them when we want to create a function or (procedure)?

Comment: Is this a homework problem?  The wikipedia article (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MIPS_architecture#MIPS_assembly_language )explains the "jal" and "jr" instructions, perhaps it answers your question.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Firstly, you might want to check [this](http://logos.cs.uic.edu/366/notes/mips%20quick%20tutorial.htm) quick MIPS reference. It really helped me.

Secondly, to explain `jal`, `jr` and `$ra`. What `jal <label>` does is jump to the `label` label and store the *program counter* (think of it as the address of the current instruction) in the `$ra` register. Now, when you want to return from `label` to where you initially were, you just use `jr $ra`.

Here's an example:

```
.text
main:
li $t0, 1
jal procedure # call procedure
li $v0, 10
syscall

procedure:
li $t0, 3
jr $ra # return
```

You will notice when running this in a SPIM emulator that the value left in `$t0` is 3, the one loaded in the so-called *procedure*.

Hope this helps.

Comment: It looks like the reference sheet is no longer available

Answer (score 11):

1.the first two are instructions,the third it's kind of special register

- jal=jump and link (Address of following instruction put in $ra,and jump to target address)
- jr=jump to specify register
- $ra=return address

we often use the instruction like this ...

- jr $ra  (Copy $ra to program counter)

it means return(jump) to the address saved in $ra .

2.

Here's an example function (procedure) in C

```
int main(){
   x=addthem(a,b);
}
int addthem(int a, int b){
   return a+b;
}
```

function in MIPS

```
.text
main:    #assume value a is already in $t0, b in $t1
    add $a0,$0,$t0   # it's the same function as move the value
    add $a1,$0,$t1 
    jal addthem      # call procedure
    add $t3,$0,$v0   # move the return value from $v0 to where we want
    syscall

addthem:
    addi $sp,$sp,-4     # Moving Stack pointer
    sw $t0, 0($sp)      # Store previous value

    add $t0,$a0,$a1     # Procedure Body
    add $v0,$0,$t0      # Result

    lw $t0, 0($sp)      # Load previous value
    addi $sp,$sp,4      # Moving Stack pointer 
    jr $ra              # return (Copy $ra to PC)
```

Answer (score 2):

You will want to read the [System V Application Binary Interface, MIPS RISC Processor Supplement](http://math-atlas.sourceforge.net/devel/assembly/mipsabi32.pdf). This describes the conventions used for calling functions, in particular how the stack is managed and parameters are exchanged (there is no hardware stack in MIPS, everything is a matter of software conventions, and the ABI defines those conventions).

The document above assumes some basic knowledge of what MIPS instructions do, so you will also need the [MIPS32 Architecture for Programmers](http://www.mips.com/products/architectures/mips32/), in particular volume II (instruction set), which describes the detailed effect of each instruction. But, do yourself a favor, download and read volume I (introduction) first.

The `jal` instruction is the "*jump* and *link*" opcode. It *jumps* at the target address (which is the address of the first opcode of the called procedure) while saving the current instruction pointer into the *link register*, which is register 31 (to be precise, it saves in register 31 the value *x*+8, where *x* is the address of the `jal` opcode itself).

Answer (score 0):

1. 

- **jal:** aka jump and link against any function name will redirect you to the required function.
- **jr $ra:** It returns the value from a function that was called.

2. 

main function:

```
   .data

            x: .word 3                        # initializing x to be 3
            y: .word 5                        # initializing y to be 5
            answer: .word 0                   # intialzing answer to be 0
            prompt: .asciiz "Add X to Y: "    # console prompt for final answer

   .text

   .globl main

   .ent main

    main:

             lw $a0, x                         # pass arguments to function $a0 - x, $a1 - y
             lw $a1, y
             jal adds                          # adds function is called
             sw $v0, answer                    # answer from the returned value

             la $a0, prompt                    # displaying prompt on the console
             li $v0, 4
             syscall

             lw $a0, answer                    # displaying final answer on the console
             li $v0, 1
             syscall

             li $v0, 10                        # end program
             syscall

    .end main
```

adds function:

```
    .globl adds

    .ent adds

    adds:                                      # adds function

              li $v0, 0                                          
              add $v0, $a0, $a1                # adding arguments to the callee
              jr $ra                           # return

   .end adds
```