# Substring question on mips assembly language

Tags: mips, mips32, mips64

Please help as soon as possible...
Write a MIPS assembly language program that prompts the user to input two strings (each should be no longer than 50 characters including the null terminator). Your program should determine whether the second string is a substring of the first. If it is, then your program should print out the first index in which the second string appears in the first. For example, if the first string is “Hello World” and the second string is “lo”, then the program should print out 3, i.e. the starting index of “lo” in “Hello World.” If the second string is not contained in the first string, then your program should print out -1.

Comment: What have you tried so far? If you don't know where to start, heavily simplify the program and increment it with functions and jump statements, step by step; because for now it might seem over complicated to you. You could start with printing -1 for example, add more and come back when you got stuck with actual code. We don't just give you the solution, because you wouldn't learn from it.

Comment: Also, for any algorithm, like finding the substring in a string, you should write them in a language like C or python (or whatever you've seen so far). It's much easier to translate the algorithm to C code and then to MIPS. It will even help you if you leave it in the comments, so you can see quickly what the program is supposed to do.

Comment: I started taking the input.. and then read both the string and after that I need a bit clue

Comment: Can you do it in C or other non-assembly language?

Comment: Then you can continue with testing if the first character of the substring appears in the main string. If you _really_ can't reproduce the algorithm, you can check the answer below, but try yourself first, because on a test, you can't ask our help either. If you haven't seen python or C, I'm afraid we can't help you out.

Answer (score 0):

To be able to understand what you have to implement at assembly level, the first thing you should do, is understanding the high-level algorithm. Why?

- It's easier for you to see all the cases and edge-cases in time!
- To look back at *what have I been trying to do again?* in the middle of programming the Assembly version.
- To quickly see which variables you (certainly) need.

I wrote following program (forgive me, python has been a while for me):

```py
def is_in_string_1(string, substring):
    """
        aaba: a, b, ab, ba, aba (last one will fail)
    """
    length = len(string)
    sublength = len(substring)

    if (sublength == 0):
        return True

    j = 0
    for i in range(0, length):
        if string[i] != substring[j]:
            j = 0
        else:
            j += 1
            if j == sublength:
                return True
    return False

def is_in_string_2(string, substring):
    """
        aaba: a, b, ab, ba, aba
    """
    length = len(string)
    sublength = len(substring)
    for i in range(0, length + 1 - sublength):  # string: aabc; substring: c; length: 4; sublength: 1; indexes: 0,1,2,3;
        is_substring = True
        for j in range(0, sublength):           # for the sake of the algorithm, no slicing here
            if string[i+j] != substring[j]:
                is_substring = False
                break
        if is_substring:
            return True
    return False
 
stringTuples = [
    ("aaa", "aa"),
    ("aaa", "aaa"),
    ("aaa", "aab"),
    ("abc", "bc"),
    ("abc", "a"),
    ("abc", "abc"),
    ("aaa", ""),
    ("aaa", "b")
]

for stringTuple in stringTuples:
    print(
        stringTuple[0],
        stringTuple[1],
        ':',
        is_in_string_1(stringTuple[0], stringTuple[1]),
        is_in_string_2(stringTuple[0], stringTuple[1]),
        sep='\t'
    )
```

I first thought I could optimize the standard solution (`is_in_string_2`), leaving out the second for-loop (`is_in_string_1`), but after some thinking I already found out it would fail (the edge-case wasn't even in any of my test-data!) - so I left it as an example for how important it is that you use a correct algorithm.

The program produces the following output:

```
aaa     aa      :       True    True
aaa     aaa     :       True    True
aaa     aab     :       False   False
abc     bc      :       True    True
abc     a       :       True    True
abc     abc     :       True    True
aaa             :       True    True
aaa     b       :       False   False
aaba    aba     :       False   True
```

Notice how all output was correct, except for the last line, where the first algorithm is wrong.

Before you continue:

- You have to make your own `len()` function in MIPS; note that all string are (if I remember correctly) null terminated, so you'll have to count all non-null characters of a string, or in other words, count how many characters precede the null-terminator.
- You should use `j`, `$ra` and `jr` calls to go to a "function" or [subroutines](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4206363/the-functions-procedures-in-mips). (Search)
- While in one, you can call other functions [using the stack](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15100476/mips-relevant-use-for-a-stack-pointer-sp-and-the-stack/15101292#15101292). (Search)

Comment: in python i can do that but playing with registers is tough

Comment: Of course it will take much more code, since you're working at low level, but you should be able to do so. You need to convert the python algorithm into mips code, so as I told, you'll have to create your own function to find the length of a string first.